# pandas merge inner skip other columns in right dataframe

Tags: pandas, merge

I have two dataframe like,

df1

```
name value
A    1
B    2
A    3
D    4
```

df2

```
name class
A    1
B    3
E    4
```

tried `pd.merge(df1,df2,on='name',how='inner')`

The output im getting is

```
name value class
A       1   1
A       3   1
B       2   3
```

my expected output is,

```
name  value
A       1   
A       3   
B       2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter column for one column `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2[['name']],on='name',how='inner')
```

What working same like:

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2[['name']])
```

Another solution is use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering:

```
df = df1[df1['name'].isin(df2['name'])]
```